# Place SQLAlchemy event listener on many-to-many table

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm trying to detect when a many-to-many relationship is created or deleted, but I'm having trouble figuring out the right event to listen for.

Let's say I have a `User` model and a `Team` model, and I'm using a membership table to define which users belong to which teams. Here's a simple schema (using Flask-SQLAlchemy's base model):

```
membership_table = db.Table('membership', db.metadata,
    db.Column('user_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('user.id')),
    db.Column('team_id', db.Integer, db.ForeignKey('team.id')),
    db.PrimaryKeyConstraint('user_id', 'team_id'))

class User(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'user'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
    teams = db.relationship('Team', secondary=membership_table, backref='users')

class Team(db.Model):
    __tablename__ = 'team'
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True)
    name = db.Column(db.String(64))
```

What I want to do is detect when someone joins or leaves the team, and trigger an event that can do something with this information (e.g. send a notification somewhere: "Dave joined the Yankees"; "Sarah left the Mets").

I tried first attaching `after_insert` and `after_delete` events directly to the membership table, but this simply failed with an `AttributeError: after_delete` exception, which was more or less what I expected given that it's not a model like the others.

I tried attaching a `set` listener to `User.teams`:

```
@event.listens_for(User.teams, 'set')
def membership_updated(target, value, oldvalue, initiator):
    # compare `oldvalue` to `newvalue` to determine membership change
```

However this event is simply never triggered when I add or remove users from a team

I tried simply listen for updates to `Team`:

```
@event.listens_for(Team, 'after_update')
def test(mapper, connection, target):
    # check current membership via `target.users`
```

This is correctly triggered when membership changes, but the problem is I can't really reason about what's happening. Maybe someone simply edited the team name, and the membership hasn't changed at all. And if it has changed, how? Was someone added or deleted?

I'm a bit stuck on where to go next, or how else to get the necessary information.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In order to "detect when someone joins or leaves the team" listen for the [append](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents.append) and [remove](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/events.html#sqlalchemy.orm.events.AttributeEvents.remove) events on `Team.users` relationship:

```
@event.listens_for(Team.users, 'append')
def receive_team_users_append(target, value, initiator):
    print(value.name, 'added to team', target.name)

@event.listens_for(Team.users, 'remove')
def receive_team_users_append(target, value, initiator):
    print(value.name, 'removed from team', target.name)
```

The event handlers will also fire if you append a team to a user's teams collection, thanks to [how backref / back_populates mirror operations](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/backref.html) between the 2 relationship properties.

Comment: Brilliant! I didn't even know about these events, exactly what I needed. I should note that I got the exception `AttributeError: type object 'Team' has no attribute 'users'` when I listened on `Team.users`, so I had to do the reverse and listen on `User.teams` (this makes sense I suppose, since I defined both sides of the relationship inside the User model). I've tested this in my code and it works perfectly. Thanks again for teaching me something new.

Comment: The mappers are completely initialized the first time you use them, so if you tried to use `Team.users` before, it wouldn't actually yet exist because [`Team` is resolved lazily](http://docs.sqlalchemy.org/en/latest/orm/relationship_api.html#sqlalchemy.orm.relationship.params.argument) since it is passed as a Python evaluable string to the relationship. I hope that makes some sense.